# Error installing Docker - curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 13847)

Tags: linux, docker, curl, terminal

> I am trying to install docker with curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o
>   get-docker.sh

it returns:

```
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 13847)
```

Comment: Do you have write access in the directory?

Comment: Great. I have posted an answer. Please accept the same. When you solve the problem on your own you should post an answer, else you should give other person who helped a chance to post the answer

Comment: Problem was write access you right But the reason i got to know that is Docker Needs sudo permission

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `0` in the error may indicate that you may not have correct permissions in the directory. So either use `sudo` or correct the permissions and then run the command again

Answer (score 2):

Problem is write permission

## Docker Needs sudo permission

> sudo curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior "curl: (23) Failed writing body" while i was using the root user.
Typing my command directly without sudo solves my issue.